# Check if serial device is working, reboot otherwise

Tags: linux, bash

I have a BeagleBone Black running Debian with a 868Mhz dongle attached via USB which shows up at /dev/ttyACM0 
In some cases, after a reboot the device doesn't show up. Therefore I wrote the following bash script and added it to crontab (@reboot)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Checks if CUL is available. Reboots otherwise
sleep 5m
if [ "ls /dev | grep ttyACM0" ]; 
then
  echo "CUL is available"
else
  echo "CUL is not available. Rebooting..."
  reboot
fi
```

But this approach seems not working.

Comment: Note that the /dev/ttyACM* nodes are just bytes in a file table, and do not indicate that a device is present.  On a system where they are dynamically created by a daemon such as udev, they might indicate that udev thinks a device is present, but on a primitive system nodes may simply be a permanent part of the file system.  If you think udev is responsible for their creation/removal and knows the truth then you then you can look at that, otherwise you may want to try opening the device to see if the kernel thinks it is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your if condition should be:

```
[ -c /dev/ttyACM0 ]
```

& perhaps you should also add more checks for major & minor numbers.

[Here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) is a link to guide for `bash if`.

Comment: What does the -c stand for?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your script always says CUL is available and never reboots.. your `if` condition is just a string, and it will always return true. Replace it with a command substitution, and add an actual condition in there (`-n` tests to see if a string is non-zero length):

```bash
if [ -n "$(ls /dev | grep ttyACM0)" ];
```

Comment: It will list all `/dev/*ttyACM0*`s. It is wrong technically, but may still serve your purpose :-) .